# How can i use cloud function with app in Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I wrote a function for verify idToken. My app in localHost and function deployed in Firebase, works normaly. But when i do `yarn build` and deploy of my React application  in Firebase, it doesn't work. What appears is the html of the index file of the build folder on the screen, when I click on the component that calls the function. In the package.json file, I wrote the proxy, with a function path in Firebase, and in component, I call the function with `axios.post (...)`. Should I fix something to make it work right after deploying?

in my package.json of src i have:

```
"proxy": "https://us-central1-teste.cloudfunctions.net/",
```

in my component i have:

```
const user = yield auth.currentUser
    const {ra} = user
    const datas = yield new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(axios.post('/auth?token='+ra)) 
    })
if (datas.data === user.uid){
       ...
    }else{
        ...
    }
```

in my cloud function i have:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

exports.auth = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {   
const idToken = request.query.token
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
.then( decodedToken => {
    response.send(decodedToken.uid)  
    return 
}).catch( error => {
    response.send(error.errorInfo.code)
    return
})  
})
```

Comment: What are the contents of your firebase.json?

Comment: @chris, `{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}`   My function is in functions/index

Comment: someone knows how can i do this? It is cors's problem?

Comment: If it is a cors problem, please post your browser console showing an error after trying to call your function

Comment: When I enter in the component that uses the cloud function, what appears on the screen is all the content of the build / index html. I did `yarn build` of `create-react-app` and then`firebase deploy`

Comment: In your component, try using resolve(axios.post('https://us-central1-teste.cloudfunctions.net/auth?token='+ra))

Comment: @chris, it doesn't work :/

Comment: Try adding https, resolve(axios.post('https://us-central1-teste.cloudfunctions.net/auth?token='+ra))

Comment: it doesn't work too :(

Comment: Please try removing "proxy": "https://us-central1-teste.cloudfunctions.net/", from package.json and use https, `resolve(axios.post('https://us-central1-teste.cloudfunctions.net/auth?token='+ra))`

Comment: i remoded in package.json and put in component: `resolve(axios.post('https://us-central1-test.cloudfunctions.net//auth?token='+ra))` and work using vscode in localHost, and when i did deploy of the build folder,  before it appeared the build/index html in the page, now appears Network Error. I don't understand... the path of my cloud functions is `https://us-central1-teste.cloudfunctions.net/auth`, but my proxy was: `us-central1-teste.cloudfunctions.net/` and the final path in component was `/auth`, and then i grouped it, `....net//auth`. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is CORS! Try do this:

In your component:

```
const data = yield new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(axios.post('https://us-central1-teste.cloudfunctions.net/auth?token='+ra))
})
```

In your function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

exports.auth = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {   
const idToken = request.query.token
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
.then( decodedToken => {
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") 
    response.send(decodedToken.uid)  
    return 
}).catch( error => {
    response.send(error.errorInfo.code)
    return
})  
})
```

If you want to restrict access to only your system, change * to `'https//:(system's_name)'`